# Get number from custom random distribution

Tags: anylogic

I have a custom distribution that is discrete. How can I retrieve a number from it and model it as my agents per arrival ?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I could not duplicate this problem so I assume your CD data is faulty. Try to redo with a simple CD with 3-4 data values only. Works like a charm here. Or are you using some other CD somewhere else, causing the prob? What is the console showing?

Comment: I had another CD hidden somewhere else. Thanks!!

Comment: cool. Always click on that "Console" link in the error, it gives you hints as to where exactly the problem is. And also share that as a screenshot, helps us :)

Answer (score 0):

Posting an answer since this question was partially answered in the comment section

In order to find the exact object that caused the error remember to click on the first Blue highlighted piece of text in the console where the error gets printed out.

[image]

You need to do this inside the AnyLogic IDE console and not the model console as there you will not be redirected to the location of the error inside the model.